# string find doesn't return the expected result

Tags: string, lua

I'm tryng to check in lua if
AGM-65D
is found in 
"LAU-117,AGM-65D"

but string.find("LAU-117,AGM-65D", "AGM-65D")
and string.match("LAU-117,AGM-65D", "AGM-65D")

both return nil. Does someone could suggest me why? maybe the comma or the "-" symbol must be used in a different way?

thanks

Comment: `string.find("LAU-117,AGM-65D", "AGM-65D", 1, true)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `string.find` and `string.match` will search for a `pattern`, and not for a plain string. And your search fails because symbol `-` is a special character in pattern matching.

To make it work, "escape" special characters with `%` sign, make it "AGM%-65D"

edit: A comment from Egor reminds us there's optional argument to `string.find` to make it search for a plain text. In simple search cases it should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks! sadly I got the "AGM-65D" string from another chunk, so I need to find a way to replace - with %-. string.gsub obviously didn't do that.

Comment: found!... I had to escape the escape character, so:
string.gsub("AGM-65D", "-", "%%-" )
produces
"AGM%-65D" as needed

Comment: @user3204845 See the comment from Egor, there's often overlooked option that makes `string.find` to search for plain texts :)